# How to add parameter to dependency injection via HostBuilder?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a simple `HostBuilder` setup:

```
private void BuildServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddHttpClient<IApiClient, ApiClient>();

}
```

... where:

```
class ApiClient : IApiClient {
    public ApiClient(HttpClient httpClient, ClientOptions options) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

I have a `ClientOptions` object configured. How do I *register* it so it will be injected into `ApiClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give this a shot, but I am not 100% sure this is what you are asking for.

Typically, you would inject it in to your pipeline. So let's say you have `ClientOptions` set up this way:

> ClientOptions.cs

```
public interface IClientOptions
{
    int DeriveSomeValue();
}

public sealed class ClientOptions : IClientOptions
{
    public int DeriveSomeValue() => 42;
}
```

You would then inject it in to your pipeline:

```
services.AddTransient<IClientOptions, ClientOptions>();
// or: services.AddScoped<IClientOptions, ClientOptions>();
// or: services.AddSingleton<IClientOptions, ClientOptions>();
```

Once that is done, you can inject it in to `IApiClient` like so:

```
public sealed class ApiClient : IApiClient {

    private readonly IClientOptions _clientOptions;

    public ApiClient(HttpClient httpClient, IClientOptions options) {
        _clientOptions = options;
        var myDerivedValue = _clientOptions.DeriveSomeValue();
    }
}
```

I am hoping that's what you are asking, if not, please let me know and I can clarify.

Comment: Looks like it is what I'm looking for. I'll give it a go and we'll see what happens.

Comment: Used the following:  
`services.AddTransient<IClientOptions, ClientOptions>((provider) => new ClientOptions() { DerivedValue = derivedValue });`

Comment: @IAbstract -- yes, that will work too. What's nice about that method is you can pull in other services to get values from using `provider.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>()`